Difficulties in the proof of finiteness of n-Selmer group using cohomology
I was reading the proof of finiteness of n-Selmer group $S^n(E/\mathbb{Q})$ from Milne's Elliptic curve book(1st Edition). While reading the proof I had some difficulties in some arguments.
1st Question: In Milne's book,
Lemma 3.8: For any finite Galois extension $L$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ and integer $n \geq 1$, the kernel of $$S^{(n)}(E/\mathbb{Q}) \longrightarrow S^{(n)}(E/L)$$
is finite.
In the proof the author claims that the kernel of
$$H^1(\mathbb{Q}, E[n]) \longrightarrow H^1(L, E[n])$$
is finite and the kernel of the map is $H^1(Gal(L/\mathbb{Q}), E(L)[n])$. Where $H^1(K, E)= H^1(Gal(\bar{K}/K),E)$.
I don't understand why the kernel is this.
2nd Question: The author conside the homomorphism  $$f : L^\times {\xrightarrow{a \mapsto (ord_{\mathfrak{p}}(a))} }\bigoplus_{\mathfrak{p}\subset \mathcal{O}_L, ~ \mathfrak{p} \text{ prime }} \mathbb{Z},$$ and claimed that cokernel of this map is the ideal class group $C$.
My question is why this definition of ideal class group matches with our actual definition using fractional ideal.
3rd Question: corollary 3.12 says that When $T$ is a finite set of prime ideals in $L$, the groups $U_T$ and $C_T$ defined by the exactness of the sequence
$$0 \longrightarrow U_T \longrightarrow L^\times {\xrightarrow{a \mapsto (ord_{\mathfrak{p}}(a))}  \longrightarrow }   \bigoplus_{\mathfrak{p}\notin T} \mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow C_T \longrightarrow 0$$ are, respectively, finitely generated and finite.
I don't understand the meaning of the natation used $U_T$ and $C_T$.
4th Question: How this corollary is useful to prove the next lemma given in the book i.e lemma 3.13 : Assume that $L$ contains the $n^{th}$-unity root. For any finite subset $T$ of $M_L$ containing $M_K^\infty$ , let $N$ be the kernel of
$$a \longrightarrow (ord_{\frak{p}}(a) (\mod n)) : L^\times/L^{\times n} \longrightarrow \bigoplus_{\frak{p}\notin T}  \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$$
Then there is an exact sequence
$$0 \longrightarrow U_T /U_T^n \longrightarrow N \longrightarrow C_T[n]$$
Therefore $N$ is a finite group.
Proof of the lemma 3.13 isn't properly clear to me.
Any kind of help or comment is welcomed.
Thanks in advance.

(Not sure any of these questions are at the right level for this forum, but here the comments that may help.)

question : Inflation-restriction sequence.

question : The target can be identified with the group of fractional ideals. Each such ideal is a product of prime ideals of the form $\mathfrak{p}_1^{a} \cdot \mathfrak{p}_2^{b} \cdots $ with $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$; it is a usual ideal if all exponents are positive. Now map this to the vector $(a,b,\dots)$ in the target group. The image of $f$ corresponds to principal ideals. So the cokernel is by definition the class group.

I don't understand that question. $U_T$ is defined to be the kernel of the given map $g\colon L^\times \to \bigoplus_{\mathfrak{p}\not\in T} \mathbb{Z}$ and $C_T$ is the cokernel. $U_T$ is the group of $T$-units and Dirichlet's theorem for the usual units also work for $U_T$ to show that it is finitely generated. Similar for $C_T$ and the usual class group.

question : Make a diagram with the given exact sequence from the 3rd question having four non-zero terms on top and another copy at the bottom. The vertical maps are multiplication-by-$n$ maps (or powering-by-$n$ maps if the group is written multiplicatively). Now the cokernel of the first vertical map is $U_T/U_T^n$, the cokernel of the second is $L^\times/(L^\times)^n$ and the third vertical map has cokernel $\bigoplus_{\mathfrak{p}\not \in T} \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. To show the new exact sequence for $N$ is now a diagram chase problem, that I think I should not spell out.



I have one small doubt in the proof of lemma 3.13 that the author said that class of [ord(a)/n] is in C_T. Why it is so?

$\operatorname{ord}{\mathfrak{p}}(a)$ is a multiple of $n$ if you are in $N$. So the vector $(\operatorname{ord}{\mathfrak{p}}(a)/n)$ is a well defined element in $\bigoplus_{\mathfrak{p}\not\in T} \mathbb{Z}$ and hence gives an element of $C_T$ by definition. It is $n$-torsion because its $n$-th power is the principal ideal $(a)$.

Ok thanks. C_T is additive group so instead of n-th power that will be n time
